# Create A Zip without the original directory located within

Tags: powershell, zip, archive

I'm attempting to create a zip from from a directory that directly contains the contents of the source directory and not the source directory then the content, which will then be uploaded to Azure.

So I have C:\temp\aFolder, create a zip from that using either the Write-Zip PSCXE

```
write-zip c:\temp\test c:\temp\test2.zip
```

or the Create-7zip function

```
function create-7zip([String] $aDirectory, [String] $aZipfile){
    [string]$pathToZipExe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-zip\7z.exe";
    [Array]$arguments = "a", "-tzip", "$aZipfile", "$aDirectory", "-r";
   & $pathToZipExe $arguments;
}

create-7zip "c:\temp\test" "c:\temp\test.zip"
```

Both ways will create a ZIP archive with the source directory located within.

So it'll be: TEST.ZIP -> TEST -> myContent.

What I want is: TEST.ZIP -> myContent. Is this possible? I can't find anything on this.

Any ideas/help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: Since I can't answer my own question**

OH MY GOD. @MJOLNIR has saved me again, I JUST FOUND his answer on another post. I apologize.

The answer is to use (If you have .NET 4.5 installed)

```
$src = "c:\temp\test"
$dst = "c:\temp\test3.zip"
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" )
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($src, $dst)
```

Will produce the TEST.ZIP -> Contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the `ZipFile` class is not supported prior to .Net Framework 4.5.

Neither the latest and greatest Framework nor external tools are actually required, though. Something like this should also work:

```psh
$folder  = 'C:\temp\test'
$zipfile = 'C:\path\to\your.zip'

# create the zip file
$b = 'P', 'K', 5, 6 | % { [char]$_ }
$b += 1..18 | % { [char]0 }
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($zipfile, [byte[]]$b)

$app = New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application'

$src = $app.NameSpace($folder)
$dst = $app.NameSpace($zipfile)

# copy items from source folder to zip file
$dst.CopyHere($src.Items())

# wait for copying to complete
do {
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
} until ($src.Items().Count -eq $dst.Items().Count)
```

Comment: Very cool! Luckily I can use the 4.5 framework on my Server which is where my script will be running, but I'll definitely keep this in mind if ( most likely WHEN ) I'll need to do such a task on a previously implemented framework. Seems odd to me that creating a ZIP isn't a simple task in PS ( at least not to a novice like myself who would have no idea how to create the code you supplied o.O I can barely even interpret it )

Comment: The first 4 bytes (`PK..`) are what defines a zip file. The other 18 zero bytes simply increase the file size to the required minimum of 22 bytes.