# Unzip with powershell does not work

Tags: function, powershell, unzip

Here is my code :

```
$e = "D:\Users\myname\Desktop\Folder\ghjkl.zip"
$f = "D:\Users\myname\Desktop\Folder\zipfiles"

function Expand-ZIPFile($file, $destination)
{
    $files = (Get-ChildItem $file).FullName

    $shell = new-object -com shell.application

    $files | %{
        $zip = $shell.NameSpace($_)

        foreach ($item in $zip.items()) {
           $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item)
        }
    }
}

Expand-ZIPFile $e $f
```

It returns no error
But there is nothing in "zipfiles" folder

What is wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: I just ran your code and it's working for me. Ensure that you have read/write access to the given folder. Users is a System folder. If you can then try to run the script in administration mode.

Comment: Are you running this code from a PowerShell script? If so you most likely you have the inverse problem to the one described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23087140/1630171). You need to wait until the unzip operation is complete. Premature termination of the script also destroys the `Shell.Application` object, thus interrupting the unzip operation.

Comment: Exactly, I m running it from a PowerShell script.

What s the solution ? Start-Sleep -s 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally,

I've changed .rar to .zip for testing the code.

File corrupted, script stopped when unzip is asked

Thanks for answers